# Interview Que - How to troubleshoot ASP.Net live application page crash?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config

In live application if client got page crash by showing contact administrator message. What will you do to trouble shoot this issue?

In local environment this issue is not getting. All data related to this page is correct. You tried all possible ways and not able to find the root cause.

Comment: Have you tried "contact administrator" :) ... at least it could have helped you to narrow down that it is unlikely issue with CSS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first turn off the Contact Administrator error message page
from something like -

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
```

To

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This will show what error is actually happening in the live environment. Then you can go through the stack trace shown in the error and can analyze the issue. Then you can revert back the config setting to original Live configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool in debugging a problem like this is to ensure that you have proper logging of exceptions in the application. Without that it becomes very difficult to track down environment specific errors.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you might try is using Application_Error event handler in Global.asax to catch an exception and to send an email when an error occurs.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    // At this point we have information about the error
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

    Exception exception = ctx.Server.GetLastError();


    string errorInfo =
        "<br><b>Time:</b> " + DateTime.Now.ToString() +
        "<br><b>Offending URL:</b> " + ctx.Request.Url.ToString() +
        "<br><b>Referring URL:</b> " + ctx.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() +
        "<br><br><b>Query String:</b> " + ctx.Request.QueryString.ToString() +
        "<br><br><b>IP Address:</b> " + ctx.Request.UserHostAddress +
        "<br><br><b>Form:</b> " + ctx.Request.Form.ToString() +
        "<br><br><b>Source:</b> " + exception.Source +
        "<br><br><b>Message:</b> " + exception.Message +
        "<br><br><b>Stack trace:</b> " + exception.StackTrace;        

    EmailNotifier.SendError(errorInfo, "Website Error");        
}
```